# Trouble with Ubuntu 14.04 Install

Tags: boot, 14.04, usb, system-installation, windows-8

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my HP Pavilion Sleekbook in order to be able to multiboot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04, but my usb drive does not boot correctly. I have tried using Pendrive Linux and Unetbootin but I get the same result. I have changed the boot priority to USB Drives but when I start my computer with the USB Drive plugged in, it results in the screen flashing on and off and I get no Ubuntu related response.

I would really like to get it to work, but right now I have no idea of whats wrong. Please help!

Comment: Maybe [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) will help. (If not, you can [edit] your question to provide more details about what you've done--including about the suggestions there--and exactly what happened. Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an issue with UEFI.  See if you can disable UEFI and boot using Legacy.  Your Windows 8.1 will have to use UEFI if you installed it using UEFI (I think), so you might have to switch between those constantly in your BIOS when you want to change OSs.  Please let me know if you do not know how to disable UEFI and enable Legacy, or run into further issues doing so.  I will be happy to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have disabled secure boot.

If you get to the screen that says "Try Ubuntu" "Install Ubuntu"
run the disc check to make sure the USB has all the necessary 
files.

If it does and you still cannot boot from usb, then you have to 
modify the boot file.  When you get to the screen with 
"Try Ubuntu" type "e".  Replace "splash quite" with "nomodeset"
Then hit ctrl-x.  It should boot from usb then.  At least this 
is what worked for me.